# SQL Server trigger to add / update table from a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that I want to add / update when a new row is added to a view but I am struggling to make this work.

My target table is Course Learner Progress and my view is `Quiz_Results_For_Course_Learner_Progress`.

I have created the view from a table that records quiz scores and is populated by a Zapier zap so I can't add a trigger to that table - which is why I have created the view of that table.

My trigger is as follows:

```
create trigger Update_Course_Progress_Quiz_Scores
on Quiz_Results_For_Course_Learner_Progress
instead of insert 
as
    declare @CompanyID int = (select CompanyID 
                              from LEARNERS.dbo.ILR 
                              where LEARNERID = LearnerID)

    Merge Course_Learner_Progress as t
    using inserted as s on t.CourseID = s.CourseID 
                        and t.ModuleID = s.ModuleID 
                        and t.LearnerID = s.LearnerID 
                        and t.ContentID = s.ContentID

    when not matched by Target then 
        insert (CompanyID, LearnerID, CourseID, ModuleID, ContentID, ContentType, Passmark, Score, [Status])
        values (@CompanyID, s.LearnerID, s.CourseID, s.ModuleID,
                s.ContentID, 4, s.Passmark, s.Quiz_Score, s.Status)

    when matched then 
        update  
        set t.Score = s.Quiz_Score,
            t.Status = s.[Status]
;
```

I can create the trigger successfully, but it doesn't insert / update a row in the `Course_Learner_Progress` table.

I would really welcome some help on this

Comment: Triggers on views only trigger when DML targets the view as the "table" to INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE. They don't fire when changes are made to the base table(s) that they are built on.

Comment: Are you sure that inserts by the Zapier are done on `Update_Course_Progress_Quiz_Scores` and not on `Course Learner Progress`?

Comment: The results from the Zap are stored in the a table dbo.Quiz_Results so I can't add a trigger to that table which is why I created a view of that table. I was hoping that the view would then be able to populate the Course_Learner_Progress table with new results

Comment: Also the select CompanyID to fill  up the CompanyID variable seems suspusious. This could result in more than one value, causing your trigger to throw an exception

Comment: Then you should write your trigger on table `dbo.Quiz_Results` Why do you think you cannot write the trigger on that table ?

Comment: An other option is to create a stored procedure that the Zap has to call in stead of inserting directly. In that stored procedure you can do your inserts in `dbo.Quiz_Results`and all other updates that you need

Comment: Hello GuidoG - I don't think you can have a Zap that feeds a table with a trigger. I tried this yesterday and got errors. I didn't know that Zaps could call a stored procedure - I need to take a look at that option. I think from your response and @Damien_The_Unbeliever response I can't run this trigger off a view so I will need to work something else out

Comment: What do you mean with `I don't think you can have a Zap that feeds a table with a trigger`? Inserting in a table will always work it does not matter if that table has a trigger or not, unless there is an error in the code of that trigger off course. I think you have some wrong ideas on how a database works or something

Comment: I have tried to add a trigger to a table that has data added to it from a zap but I get the error... internal returned (500) Internal Server Error......The target table 'Quiz_Results' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.

Comment: That just means you have made an error in the code of that trigger. All you need to do is fix that error. Maybe start a new question and put the trigger in that question and ask what is wrong with it and why you get that error.Also show the complete create script for that table

Comment: Hi - I have found the issue - Zapier cannot add data to a table with a trigger that has an auto increment primary key. I just created a second table without a primary key sent the Zap data there as well and the trigger now updates the other table. It all works.

Comment: Triggers have no auto increment key. Triggers have no key at all. This makes no sense to me. It looks like you have some names confused here. But anyway I am glad it works for you